# iOS 7.1 CommonCrypto library complains: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (unsigned long) to CC_LONG (unsigned int)

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, md5, precision

I get the above error (in title) whilst doing a MD5 from file..  I can usually cope with these type of 32->64bit conversion issues..but in this case, I do not know what I should do as CC_MD5 is part of `CommonCrypto->CommonDigest`, a library that ships with iOS7.1. I am assuming `[inputData length]` is returning NSUInteger and therein lies the issue, however can I simply cast down from UL to UI?  I will possibly lose precision if the file is large.  Why would a library that Apple ships with require `int` in a 64 bit capable language such as iOS?  Did someone overlook something or am I being really stupid and mis-diagnosing the problem?

```
- (NSString*) getMD5FromFile:(NSString *)pathToFile {
    unsigned char outputData[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    NSData *inputData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile];
    CC_MD5([inputData bytes], [inputData length], outputData);
    [inputData release];

    NSMutableString *hash = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [hash appendFormat:@"%02x", outputData[i]];
    }

    return [hash autorelease];
}
```

From CommonCrypto->CommonDigest.h:

```
extern unsigned char *CC_MD5(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md)
```

I filed bug report with apple (#17256918) but isn't there a way to do this without the error?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug but I would expect `1.`the MD5 input length to be "unlimited" which I interpret as a 64-bit integer (possibly unsigned) and `2.`Any type with `LONG` in the name should actually be a long integer. I would log a problem with Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to cast `[inputData length]` to either `int` or `uint32_t` as you suspect.

If you want to assert that number is not too large for type you can use the `UINT32_MAX`to check. Here is an example on an NSAssert you could use.

```
    NSAssert([inputData length] < UINT32_MAX, @"too big!");
```

Comment: The length should always be considered, but in general the gripe I have about this solution is that there doesn't seem to be a macro for the max of CC_LONG, therefore you have to still make an assumption.  Persnickety perhaps, but there's no guarantee it will always be uint32_t.

Comment: @JoeyCarson yeah, I tried to avoid this assumption in [elegant way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33330099/991816).

Comment: I think you mean `>` and not `<`

Comment: I am using an assert. The assert will do nothing as long as the condition is true. So as long as the length is less than `UINT32_MAX` everything will just work. As soon as the assertion fails the "too big!" message will appear and the app will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro but I hope I didn't make a huge mistake.
For code to be a bit safer than just casting without assertion you can use this assert:

```
NSAssert([inputData length] <= (CC_LONG)-1, @"Input length is too big for unsigned CC_LONG type! Or CC_LONG became signed, which is unlikely");
```

This variant is better because it doesn't rely on UINT32_MAX, because CC_LONG can be changed in future.

P.S. I was going crazy when I first saw this trick `(CC_LONG)-1` some years ago before I realized that it's just type casting and not a sophisticated C feature related to `sizeof`. So this is a huge relieve for your brain if you struggled with it)