# iOS 64 bit support with C framework libxml2 "implicit conversion loses integer precision"

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, 32bit-64bit, libxml2

My app uses libxml2, which contains a function "xmlReadMemory(const char * buffer, 
                     int size, 
                     const char * URL, 
                     const char * encoding, 
                     int options)"

I do have a "size" to send, but it is an *NSUInteger*.

This framework is written in C, so it expects me to send an *int*, which throws a warning in my application since I am now including arm64 as a valid architecture: "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: *NSUInteger* (aka 'unsigned long') to *int*". Is there a safe way to resolve this warning?

link to framework API: http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html

Comment: this seems like a similar issue too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24148817/ios-7-1-commoncrypto-library-complains-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precis

Comment: `int isize = (int) usize; if (isize < 0 || isize != usize) Handle_Error(); else xmlReadMemory(buffer, isize, URL, rncoding, options);`

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're confident that you'll never need to pass it a value larger than the largest 32 bit integer (very unlikely) just cast it to int by adding `(int)` in front of the parameter in the function call. An unsigned 32 bit value is over 4 GB, which is more than the memory on an iPhone, and would take **HOURS** to download over the cell network.